# GeoTools 18.1 throws nullpointer using JMapFrame

Tags: java, geotools

Using below code (which i mainly got from the GeoTools site) i get a NullPointer.
For reference, i used the OGC reference url for WMS 1.3

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ServiceException {

    String[] mList = {"http://metaspatial.net/cgi-bin/ogc-wms.xml"};
    URL capabilitiesURL = WMSChooser.showChooseWMS(Arrays.asList(mList) );
    if( capabilitiesURL == null ){
        System.exit(0); // canceled
    }
    WebMapServer wms = new WebMapServer( capabilitiesURL );        

    List<org.geotools.data.ows.Layer> wmsLayers = WMSLayerChooser.showSelectLayer( wms );
    if( wmsLayers == null ){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Could not connect - check url");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    MapContent mapcontent = new MapContent();
    mapcontent.setTitle( wms.getCapabilities().getService().getTitle() );

    for( org.geotools.data.ows.Layer wmsLayer : wmsLayers ){
      WMSLayer displayLayer = new WMSLayer(wms, wmsLayer );
      mapcontent.addLayer(displayLayer);
    }
    // Now display the map
    JMapFrame.showMap(mapcontent);
}
```

The stacktrace says this:

```
WARNING: Starting schema with ServiceExceptionReport element.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.geotools.map.WMSCoverageReader.reference(WMSCoverageReader.java:432)
    at org.geotools.map.WMSCoverageReader.updateBounds(WMSCoverageReader.java:402)
    at org.geotools.map.WMSCoverageReader.addLayer(WMSCoverageReader.java:196)
    at org.geotools.map.WMSCoverageReader.<init>(WMSCoverageReader.java:126)
    at org.geotools.map.WMSLayer.<init>(WMSLayer.java:81)
    at javagisviewer.JavaGisViewer.main(JavaGisViewer.java:50)
```

I'm using Netbeans 8.2 with Java 1.8u131 (not maven)
I got rid of the next JAR files as per QuickStart ( http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/quickstart/netbeans.html ), i also removed the GDAL jar.

```
gt-arcgrid-18.1.jar
gt-arcsde-18.1.jar
gt-arcsde-common-18.1.jar
gt-epsg-hsql-18.1.jar
gt-epsg-oracle-18.1.jar
gt-epsg-postgresql-18.1.jar
gt-epsg-wkt-18.1.jar
gt-imageio-ext-gdal-18.1.jar
gt-jdbc-db2-18.1.jar
gt-jdbc-h2-18.1.jar
gt-jdbc-mysql-18.1.jar
gt-jdbc-oracle-18.1.jar
```

It looks like it's missing a Coordinate reference (srs/crs)?
I don't know where to go from here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, the code works perfectly! So you probably have a jar issue as you expect. This is why we recommend that GeoTools users use Maven so that this sort of issue doesn't arise.

Your problem is that you have removed **all** 4 of the epsg jars instead of just 3 of them as mentioned in the documentation. If you add `gt-epsg-wkt-18.1.jar` back into your project all should be fine.

Comment: thanks. I decided to try out the maven project-file, geotools dependancies are indeed very hard to find out